# Dynamic URL too long (2568 characters), trying to make it shorter

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, netbeans

[image: the message i get from the chrome console]
i'm working with a javascript on a drupal website, but the saving function seems to work only as soon as i click 2 times on the "save" button. the code that fires the function is:

```
var param ="&usuario="+usuario+"&nivel="+nivel+gano+porc_gano+gasto+porc_gasto+tengo+porc_tengo+debo+     porc_debo+plazo_debo;
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true;
s.src = server_direction +"setMisDatos?callback=respuestaGuardarMisDatos&param="+encodeURIComponent(param);
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h); //or h.appendChild(s);
```

the chrome console tells me the error is in the last line i copied, but i don't undertand what kind of error it is.

using chrome console (specifically the "network" one), i see that it's written in red, status/text "failed", type "undefined" size/content "13 B / 0 B"; when it works it's: status/text "200/OK", type "text/json", size/content "256 B/ 38B". i'm not an expert with this, is there some more information that could be useful?

the code fires a netbeans function, that stores data to a postgresql database, so i have like 100 variables that has to be stored when i click on the "save button".

The variables are written like this (in the js file):

```
var plazo_debo_casa1 = (getValor("plazo_debo_casa1"));
var plazo_debo_casa2 = (getValor("plazo_debo_casa2"));
var plazo_debo_casa3 = (getValor("plazo_debo_casa3"));
var plazo_debo_prestamo1 = (getValor("plazo_debo_prestamo1"));
var plazo_debo_prestamo2 = (getValor("plazo_debo_prestamo2"));
var plazo_debo_prestamo3 = (getValor("plazo_debo_prestamo3"));
var plazo_debo ="&plazo_debo_casa1="+plazo_debo_casa1+"&plazo_debo_casa2="+plazo_debo_casa2+"&plazo_debo_casa3="+plazo_debo_casa3+"&plazo_debo_prestamo1="+plazo_debo_prestamo1+"&plazo_debo_prestamo2="+plazo_debo_prestamo2+"&plazo_debo_prestamo3="+plazo_debo_prestamo3;
```

and then together in the "param" variable. Is it clearer now?

I installed httpfox in firefox, then i checked what happens, and finally i think i got the error: it says NS_ERROR_NET_RESET. Is it the actual error? what can i do to solve it?

I have been searching around the internet and probably my problem is that the URL is too long,

```
http://www.mirodinero.com:8080/mirodinero-war/setMisDatos?callback=respuestaGuardarMisDatos&param=%26usuario%3DIsa%20Mirodinero%26nivel%3D109%26gano_sal_neto%3D211113.45%26gano_sal_prof%3D2480%26gano_monet%3D0%26gano_renta_fija%3D0%26gano_renta_vble%3D0%26gano_inmuebles%3D2226.75%26gano_otros%3D2223.73%26gano_otros_ing%3D2411.12%26porc_gano_monet%3D0%26porc_gano_rentaf%3D0%26porc_gano_rentav%3D0%26porc_gano_inm%3D2%26porc_gano_otros%3D2%26porc_gano_otros_ing%3D1%26gasto_casa1%3D1306.46%26gasto_casa2%3D2402.38%26gasto_casa3%3D3999.57%26gasto_prestamo1%3D93475.58%26gasto_prestamo2%3D7325.88%26gasto_prestamo3%3D34090.9%26gasto_tarjetas%3D29443.2%26gasto_ibi%3D5670%26gasto_imp_otros%3D6780%26gasto_seg_inm%3D1320%26gasto_seg_pens%3D3451.22%26gasto_seg_vida%3D2330%26gasto_seg_plan%3D34230%26gasto_seg_medico%3D21220%26gasto_seg_coche%3D220%26gasto_luz%3D620%26gasto_agua%3D4550%26gasto_gas%3D320%26gasto_telef_f%3D22320%26gasto_telef_m%3D2350%26gasto_internet%3D20%26gasto_tv%3D3450%26gasto_hogar%3D20%26gasto_comida%3D20%26gasto_cenas_copas%3D20%26gasto_viajes%3D20%26gasto_vacaciones%3D220%26gasto_mobiliario%3D220%26gasto_ropa%3D2320%26gasto_transp%3D230%26gasto_otros%3D3620%26gasto_colegios%3D240%26gasto_univ%3D340%26gasto_master%3D2230%26gasto_otros_gastos%3D7323433%26porc_gasto_tarjetas%3D0%26porc_gasto_ibi%3D0%26porc_gasto_trib%3D0%26porc_gasto_seg_inm%3D0%26porc_gasto_seg_pens%3D0%26porc_gasto_seg_vida%3D2%26porc_gasto_seg_plan%3D2%26porc_gasto_seg_med%3D0%26porc_gasto_seg_coche%3D0%26porc_gasto_sum_luz%3D2%26porc_gasto_sum_agua%3D2%26porc_gasto_sum_gas%3D0%26porc_gasto_sum_teleff%3D0%26porc_gasto_sum_telefm%3D0%26porc_gasto_sum_int%3D0%26porc_gasto_sum_tv%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_hogar%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_comida%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_cenas%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_viajes%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_vacac%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_mob%3D0%26porc_gasto_nivel_ropa%3D20%26porc_gasto_nivel_transp%3D30%26porc_gasto_nivel_otros%3D30%26porc_gasto_colegios%3D2%26porc_gasto_univ%3D0%26porc_gasto_master%3D0%26porc_gasto_otros_gastos%3D23%26tengo_casa1%3D1231.11%26tengo_casa2%3D10000%26tengo_casa3%3D22240%26tengo_otras%3D23560%26tengo_monetario%3D1212.34%26tengo_planpensiones%3D23230%26tengo_otros%3D23330%26porc_tengo_casa1%3D1%26porc_tengo_casa2%3D0%26porc_tengo_casa3%3D2%26porc_tengo_otras%3D0%26porc_tengo_monet%3D0%26porc_tengo_plan%3D0%26porc_tengo_otros%3D0%26debo_casa1%3D4340%26debo_casa2%3D23450%26debo_casa3%3D23430%26debo_prestamo1%3D23330%26debo_prestamo2%3D6871.11%26debo_prestamo3%3D11340%26debo_tarjetas%3D61340%26porc_debo_casa1%3D30%26porc_debo_casa2%3D10%26porc_debo_casa3%3D12%26porc_debo_prestamo1%3D1%26porc_debo_prestamo2%3D12%26porc_debo_prestamo3%3D1%26porc_debo_tarjetas%3D4%26plazo_debo_casa1%3D230%26plazo_debo_casa2%3D450%26plazo_debo_casa3%3D122%26plazo_debo_prestamo1%3D3%26plazo_debo_prestamo2%3D12%26plazo_debo_prestamo3%3D4
```

I counted it, it's 2568 characters. So I tried to split it in two parts, since there is "what i earn", "my debts", etc. Problem is, that if my function only saves some columns, then it simply deletes the remaining one in postgres. How can this problem be solved?

since my webpage has different parts where to put the data, i thought that a good idea would be to create smaller function for parts of variable, for example putting 30 variables and the do the callback. I did like this:

```
function guardaLoQueGano(){
var nivel = parseInt(document.getElementById('progreso_nivel_total').style.marginLeft);

/*idUsusario*/
var usuario =  miGetElementsByClassName('title', document.getElementById('block-user-1'))[0].innerHTML;

/*gano*/
var gano_sal_neto = getValor("gano_sal_neto");
var gano_sal_prof = getValor("gano_sal_prof");
var gano_monet = getValor("gano_monet");
var gano_renta_fija = (getValor("gano_renta_fija"));
var gano_renta_vble = (getValor("gano_renta_vble"));
var gano_inmuebles = (getValor("gano_inmuebles"));
var gano_otros = (getValor("gano_otros"));
var gano_otros_ing = (getValor("gano_otros_ing"));

/*gano porcentajes*/
var porc_gano_monet = getValor("porc_gano_monet");
var porc_gano_rentaf = getValor("porc_gano_rentaf");
var porc_gano_rentav = getValor("porc_gano_rentav");
var porc_gano_inm = getValor("porc_gano_inm");
var porc_gano_otros = getValor("porc_gano_otros");
var porc_gano_otros_ing = getValor("porc_gano_otros_ing");

var param = "&usuario=" + usuario + "&nivel=" + nivel + "&gano_sal_neto=" + gano_sal_neto + "&gano_sal_prof=" + gano_sal_prof + "&gano_monet=" + gano_monet + "&gano_renta_fija=" + gano_renta_fija + "&gano_renta_vble=" + gano_renta_vble + "&gano_inmuebles=" + gano_inmuebles + "&gano_otros=" + gano_otros + "&gano_otros_ing=" + gano_otros_ing +     "&porc_gano_monet=" + porc_gano_monet + "&porc_gano_rentaf=" + porc_gano_rentaf + "&porc_gano_rentav=" + porc_gano_rentav + "&porc_gano_inm=" + porc_gano_inm + "&porc_gano_otros=" + porc_gano_otros + "&porc_gano_otros_ing=" + porc_gano_otros_ing;

var s = document.createElement("script");

s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true;
s.src = direccion_servidor + "setMisDatos?callback=respuestaGuardarMisDatos&param=" + encodeURIComponent(param);
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
// adesso h.appendChild(s);
h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h);
alert("Datos de lo que gano actualizados correctamente");
}
```

This kind of function works perfectly, but has a big problem: it changes the values of the columns of this function, but deletes the remaining ones. How can I create different smaller function, in a way to save only on some columns without changing the others? Shall I write the netbeans function setMisDatos to make it more clear?

**New finding:**

I've been searching in the internet, and maybe found that my problem is that i might change the GET method to a POST protocol, so that it could take any kind of length.

On my page there is a php code to call the javascript function that is:

```
  <div id="lo_que_gano" class="mis_datos" style="display:none">
<div class="generic todo_izq">

    <div class="ancho_lado_izq generic">
        <div class="texto_form generic">Salario neto</div>
        <div class="generic">
            <input class="numero" id="gano_sal_neto" type="text" value="0" onchange="calculoGano()" onkeypress="tecla('gano_sal_prof', event);"/></br>
        </div>
    </div>
  //all the values that has to be stored
 </div>
 <div class="generic botonGuardar">
    <input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="return guardaTodo()"/>
 </div>
 </div>
```

how can i convert the GET method to POST? Shall it be implemented in the javascript or in the php code? I'm sorry i'm really not an expert on this.

I tried to change &usuario= with &u=, and it works, but then when i try to change "gano_sal_neto" (i changed &gano_sal_neto= with &gsn=), it will delete the corresponding value in the postgres table (a NULL value). Where is the error now? I'm sorry but i'm really not an expert on this.

And I have an observation: why do i get error after 30 seconds, but not in that in interval?

the change i did, based on the answer i got, from "gano_sal_neto" to "gsn" in:

- the javascript file that is loaded by the source code of the page;
- the php code of the drupal page;
- the netbeans files;
- i created a new column named "gsn" in the same table as where the data are stored.

what am i missing to make the new URL work?

**Better explanation of what is happening now:**

i have 2 types of error:

in the netbeans log file, it tells me:

Code:
error: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mirodinero.web.calculos.Calculos.getTotalGano(Calculos.java:182)
    at com.mirodinero.web.calculos.CalcularSegmentos.ejecutar(CalcularSegmentos.java:65)
    at com.mirodinero.web.servlets.setMisDatos.actualizarSegmentos(setMisDatos.java:543)
where getTotalGano at those lines is:

```
public float getTotalGano() {
    float res = user.getGanoMonet() + user.getGanoRentaFija() + user.getGanoRentaVble() + user.getGanoInmuebles() + user.getGanoOtros() + user.getGanoSalNeto() + user.getGanoSalProf() + user.getGanoOtrosIng();
    return res;
}
```

and ejecutar() is:

```
public void ejecutar() {
    boolean existe = true;
    DatosUsuario datosUser = datosUsuarioFacade.findById(atributosUsuario.getIdUsuario());
    if (datosUser != null) {
        List<Cartera> lc = carteraFacade.findByIdUsuario(atributosUsuario.getIdUsuario());
        Calculos c = new Calculos(datosUser, accionesDatosFacade, fondosDatosFacade, bonosDatosFacade, lc);
        ahorroLiquido = c.getTengoDisponible() / c.getTotalGasto();
        ingresoAnual = c.getTotalGano(); /*this is line 65 */
        diferenciaGanoGasto = c.getSupDefTotal();//indica lo que gano menos lo que gasto
        modificarAtributos(c, datosUser);
    }
```

on the postgres log file, i get:

```
2012-05-22 11:10:46 CESTLOG:  could not receive data from client: Unknown winsock error 10061
2012-05-22 11:10:46 CESTLOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2012-05-22 11:19:12 CESTLOG:  CreateProcess call failed: Unknown winsock error 10004 (error code 1115)
2012-05-22 11:19:12 CESTLOG:  could not fork autovacuum worker process: Unknown winsock error 10004
```

but i don't know what does it mean. Maybe is there something i should do with pgadmin to "upgrade" the database to the changes:i added a column named gsn -real and default 0 like gano_sal_neto-, without deleting the gano_sal_neto (that still has stored the data of the users).

still nobody able to help me with this? i don't what's the problem with changing columns name in postgres, maybe a procedure i'm missing?

Comment: you should not be asking multiple questions for the same issue. if you are not receiving answers, try editing your question to be clearer and/or provide more details.

Comment: i deleted the old one, putting more information in this one, isn't it ok?

Comment: Does your code work somehow? Because I can't decipher what you're trying to do.. Assuming `h = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]` is a script inside the head tag, and `h.parentNode` is the document's `head` itself, you could simply replace it all by `$("head").append(s);`. Oh wait, you're not using JQuery? You could use `document.head.appendChild(s);` then. Also what is that script which you're inserting in the DOM for? You should post its code so we can look at that.

Comment: Also, as @jbabey said, simply editing your question will bump it up to the top, so you don't have to delete and create a new one.

Comment: Following your edit: please re-read the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: yes, but by encoding what do you mean? an algorhythm that changes the original URL to submit it, and then changes it another time when it has to pass th data to the server? (sorry, english is not my native language).

Comment: Yes. You need to figure out a way of condensing the data you are sending in your HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to change the settings in *glassfish* `HTTP service` listenings: I changed the timeouts to a bigger interval, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are doing is constructing a `<script src=...>` element, with the `src` attribute dynamically generated, it's not possible to use POST. All HTTP requests use GET. What you *may* be able to do instead is encode your querystring to make it shorter. The server-side processing can decode it to send the right script file.

For example, you don't need `&usario=` when you could call that `&u=` because your server-side process shouldn't need it to be called `usario`. You've saved five bytes just by doing that.

You could encode the values to make them shorter, and decode them server-side. I've no idea what the data actually is; this may not be practical.